# git rebase using --onto

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

[image]

The above is my tree and here is the code I've used to create it, though I would say that the code is insignificant to my question, but just in case you wish to try it out, here you go.

http://pastebin.com/gdy0cPb8

Currently I am checked out on `master` and execute `git rebase --onto <any commit> master`. This moves the pointer of master to `<any commit>`. For example, `git rebase --onto client master` moves the pointer of master to `C4` but doesn't make any other change.

I assumed that would be the default behavior because the `master` is the `[upstream]` to compare against and since it is the same branch I understand that `master` is just moved there. [[Reference git-scm.org]](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

However, the same happens even when I execute `git rebase --onto m2 master` (without first moving master to `C4`), the pointer is just moved to `C9`

I just wish to know, why does that happen?

Comment: what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am expecting `C8` to be applied on top of `C9`, I do realize there are other ways to do it but I wish to know why the mentioned command does not do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when you run `git rebase --onto m2 master`:

1. Git identifies all commits that are in your current branch but not in `<upstream>`. In this case, your upstream is master, the same as your current branch so there are no commits different.
2. Git effectively does `git reset --hard <newbase>`. Newbase is the commit specified with `--onto`, in this case `m2`. This moves the master branch to `m2`.
3. Git reapplies the commits it found in step 1. Since there are none in this case, the rebase is complete.

The only thing that happened in this process is that your master branch was moved to C9.

It sounds like what you want to do is move the master branch (including C8) on top of C9. To do this, you can just checkout master, then run `git rebase m2`. Lets do the process again.

1. Git finds the commits in master but not in m2. There is one commit, C8. Git saves this for later.
2. Git does `git reset --hard <newbase>`. Since we did not specify `--onto`, this defaults to `<upstream>` which is m2. So master moves to m2.
3. Git reapplies the commits from step 1. C8 will be reapplied now on top of C9.

You end up with

```
... C7 - C9 - C8' master m2
```

Notice I wrote `C8'` instead of `C8`. This is because `C8` will now have a new commit hash.

For the sake of argument, lets say you wanted the following graph:

```
       C8' master
      /
C4 - C5 - C6 - C7 - C9 m2
```

You can accomplish this by checking out master and running `git rebase --onto C5 C7`. Now this happens:

1. Git finds the commits in master but not in your upstream C7. It finds C8.
2. Git resets to the `<newbase>`: `git reset --hard C5`
3. Reapply commits from step 1. (C8)

Comment: Hi.. that makes perfect sense.  Thank you,  could you please change m9 to C9.

Comment: And in your last example, if I modified the rebase command to `git rebase --onto C5 C5` or `git rebase --onto C5 C6`, I would get the same result am I correct

Comment: No, all the commits after your upstream would be replayed on top of C5. So `git rebase --onto C5 C6` would result in `C4 - C5 - C6 - C7' - C8'` in master. The m2 branch would still be `C4 - C5 - C6 - C7 - C9`. Notice that C7 is now duplicated. If you specified C5 as your upstream, you would also duplicate the C6 commit.

Answer (score 3):

[`git rebase --onto X Y`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) would merge the commits *after* `Y` up to the current branch HEAD onto `X`, and move the current branch HEAD.

If the current branch is actually `Y`, then there is no commit *after* `Y` to move.
`Y` HEAD would simply be moved to `X`.

That is what happen with `git rebase --onto m2 master`

What would apply C8 to C9 would be:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto m2 C7
```

Or, simpler:

```
git checkout master
git rebase m2
```

No need of `--onto` here: you are rebasing the `master` branch on top of `m2`. That will apply `C8` on top of `C9`.